# mongodb limit elements in stream

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can anybody explain to me what is wrong with Mongoose's stream? I use mongoose and have some collection where I query 10 000 elements using stream. On stream, I want to remove each of the 10 000 element from collection.
 Example:

```
var stream = Collection.find({}).limit(10000).stream();
stream.on('data', function (item) {
    stream.pause();
    // do something
    item.remove(function (err) {
        stream.resume();
    });
});
```

And now the problem is, I limit the documents to 10 000, but it deletes more than 10000. Why?